# Spring AuthenticationManager that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, back-end

Estou tentando configurar o *oAuth2* na minha aplicação de estudo só que esta me retornando um erro que eu não estou conseguindo resolver

> **required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager'
>   that could not be found**

```
AuthorizationServerConfig.java

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends 

    AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory().withClient("client").secret("passwordClient").scopes("read", "write")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password").accessTokenValiditySeconds(1800);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
        }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

}
```

ResourceServerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ROLE");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/categorias").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.stateless(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Veja se [isso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21639553/4319922) ajuda. Aplique na sua classe `ResourceServerConfig`. No momento, você quer injetar um _bean_ que ainda não existe. Essa solução linkada ajuda a expor esse _bean_.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema da seguinte forma: na classe AuthorizationServerConfig eu acrescentei o Qualifier segue a nova forma que ela ficou

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;



@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory().withClient("angular").secret("@ngul@r0").scopes("read", "write")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password").accessTokenValiditySeconds(1800);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new InMemoryTokenStore();
}
```

}

e na classe  ResourceServerConfig eu fiz um extends de WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter,anotei apenas com @Configuration e criei o metodo  authenticationManagerBean: segue a nova forma da classe

@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Autowired
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("adm").password("admin").roles("ROLE");
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/categorias").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().csrf().disable();
}

@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
// @Override
// public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws
// Exception {
// resources.stateless(true);
// }
```

}